# How to get file from createPHPExcelObject()

Tags: php, symfony

I use component `liuggio/ExcelBundle` from https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle

I want to import a file xlsx and use createPHPObject() to catch it up
and the parameter of createPHPExcelObject() is filename then I pass a filename into it

```
/**
* @var \Liuggio\ExcelBundle\Factory
*/
private $phpexcelFactory;

$path = '/Users/Intbizth/MyProject/lottery/src/Lot/LotteryBundle/Importer/lottery.xlsx'
$phpExcel = $this->phpexcelFactory->createPHPExcelObject($path);
```

and error throw Call to a member function createPHPExcelObject() on null

The question is how to get the file from project ? Thank you for advance.

Comment: Have you read the readme ?

Comment: @Calimero Yes, I have

But finally I've found the problem.
I forget to inject service.

Comment: Good Job. That was the point of my comment :-) Best of luck for your project.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @B.Godoak Could you please answer your question so it won´t show up as `unanswered`? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solve !
I've just forget to inject `phpexcel service` into this service

```
<service id="id.of.this.service" class="path\of\this\class">
   <argument type="service" id="phpexcel" /> /** This line is what I've forget */
</service>
```